# 2D points aligning (Rotation + Translation)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is it possible to align 2d objects using only 2 reference points?
Why do we always use 3 points?

Thank you.

Edit :

If I have P1(MinX, MnY) and P2(MaxX, MaxY) I can deduce other points and look for a transformation matrix.

I want to know why only 2 points are not enough to get the transformation matrix.

[image]

Comment: Can you give some context?  For instance, a flat 2d object in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 3$ would require you to fix three points, but I don't know if that's relevant without more context from you.

Comment: I want to know why only 2 points are not enough for aligning.

Comment: Where have you seen that 3 points are needed?

Comment: I use OpenCV Libray and most functions that calculate the transformation matrix requires 3 or more points.

Comment: Can you give an example? Maybe you are looking at affine transformations, which are more general that rotation+translation ( rigid transformation)